# How do I pass a response from a Webform custom handler back to Drupal to display on the confirmation page

Tags: webforms

I have created a custom module for a custom Webform handler. The custom handler submits to an external SOAP api. There are various response options that are received back from the SOAP api that currently I am printing to screen (for testing purposes). But when using this module in production, I obviously want these responses to be displayed at the top of the confirmation page.

Is there some way to populate a token (possibly the Webform Handler Response token?), which I can then use to print the information on my confirmation page?

F

Answer (score 0):

Your two options are…

OPTION 1: Add the SOAP API's response value  as a hidden element's value using something like

```
$webform_submission->setElementData('response_value', $response->value);
$webform_submission->resave();
```

OPTION 1: Store the response in $_SESSION and use

```
\Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::confirmForm
\Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::preprocessConfirmation
```

to alter the confirmation message or page.

Comment: Thanks jrockowitz. I've tried Option 1 but I am getting a Duplicate entry error. I think it's because I am trying that within the preSave function. Do I need to alter the code to use with preSave?

Comment: Don't call $webform_submission->resave(); if you are setting the element data via ::preSave()